# SQLite Prepare Failed: database disk image is malformed iphone simulator SQLite?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Please help !

while i start app in  simulator it fires "SQLite Prepare Failed: database disk image is malformed" in i have a .db file which i have rebuild thrice.

What can cause this ?

Any solutions ?

Comment: I am using sqlite3 and framework is libsqlite3.0.dylib !

Comment: I have similar issues but on Windows Mobile, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I've used (on Windows) this program:

http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/

I've exported the database as sql (in the file menu), then I created another database, opened it with the same program and imported the sql. I didn't lose any data (luckily).
I know it's possible to use the console to do this, here is a link if you can't use Windows:

http://techblog.dorogin.com/2011/05/sqliteexception-database-disk-image-is.html

Answer (score 1):

Deleted the database and created new 1 :(

Comment: Develop your answer a little, so it may help other people